# Send HTML of page from content script to background js but message not received

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to send the DOM as a message from the contentscript to the backgroundjs, but it doesn't seem like anything is sending. In my extension, I'm adding a button to a link, then on click, it will get a preview of the website.

I've read through dozens of other links that seem to have the same problem, and I've tried most of those solutions but it still silently fails.

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "PreviewMe",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "Test",

  "permissions": [
    "<all_urls>"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["js/background.js"],
    "persistent": true

  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ],
      "js": [
        "js/contentscript.js"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**contentscript.js**

```
chrome.extension.sendMessage({}, function(response) {
    var readyStateCheckInterval = setInterval(function() {
    if (document.readyState === "complete") {
        clearInterval(readyStateCheckInterval);
        // do stuff to initialize
    }
    }, 10);
});

// send dom over to background.js
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({dom: document.body.innertHTML});
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log('HELLO WORLD');
});
```

I put the hello world console log to test, but even that isn't showing up.

Thanks.

EDIT: I thought my code was silently failing but turns out it's just logged to a separate console. Didn't know there was a separate console for background pages.

Comment: Maybe you're looking in the wrong place? Background page is opened from chrome://extensions page: [Where to read console messages from background.js in a Chrome extension?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10258029)

Comment: Ah! Thank you for the help. It was there!